# Android Downloading large JSON in AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I've 5MB of JSON to be downloaded and i make several request breaking the response from web server to 300KB, i'm using `AsyncTask{}` and able to successfully download all data but the problem here is that it takes lot of time to download and process the JSON data...

Below is the garbage collector running too frequently but i don't think it is actually freeing memory in every instance it is being called.
[image: garbage collector trying to free memory]

Can anyone clarify what is the preferred size of JSON that can be downloaded without delay or is it the problem of memory leakage as i am calling same asynctask from `onPostExecute()` or the buffer size for `http request(DefaultHttpClient-Apache)` is not enough, i know that use of `DownloadManager` is one option but is there any recommended way to fix this.

requesting AsyncTask code:

```
new DownloadJson().execute();
```

actual AsyncTask code:

```
static class DownloadJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    FirstTimeSyncParser jsonParser = new FirstTimeSyncParser();
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
             getClass().getName());
        wl.acquire();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading 14 of 18 ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        sqlHandler = new SqlHandler(context);
        tList = sqlHandler.selectTemp();
        for(Temp t:tList){
            deviceId = t.getDeviceId();
        }
        jsonReceived = new JSONObject();
        sList = new ArrayList<ActivityMark>();
        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tab_id", deviceId));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("table_name", "activitymark"));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("req_call",reqCall+""));
        jsonReceived = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(urlSync, "POST", param);

        if(jsonReceived!=null){
            JSONArray sync = null;
            try{
                actMarkSuccess = jsonReceived.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if(actMarkSuccess == 1){
                    sync = jsonReceived.getJSONArray("Sync");
                    reqAgain = jsonReceived.getInt("req_again");
                    reqCall = reqAgain;
                    for(int i=0; i<sync.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject j = sync.getJSONObject(i);
                        ActivityMark m = new ActivityMark();
                        m.setExamId(j.getInt("ExamId"));
                        m.setActivityId(j.getInt("ActivityId"));
                        m.setMark(j.getString("Mark"));
                        m.setSchoolId(j.getInt("SchoolId"));
                        m.setStudentId(j.getInt("StudentId"));
                        m.setSubjectId(j.getInt("SubjectId"));
                        sList.add(m);                       
                    }
                    sqlHandler.initializeActivityMark(sList);               
                }
            }
            catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                reqAgain=0;
            }
        }

        sqlHandler.updateTables("activitymark");
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String s){
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        wl.release();
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if(actMarkSuccess == 0){
            SyncTime.updateSyncFailure(context);
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("in.schoolcom", "in.schoolcom.MainActivity");
            context.startActivity(i);
        }else{
            SyncTime.updateSyncProgress(context);
            if(reqAgain!=0){
            //  System.gc();
                tList.clear();
                new DownloadJson().execute();
            }else{

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: post the code. how do you invoke asynctask

Answer (score 0):

The only consideration would be the network lag. Longer running processes should not be in `AsyncTasks`. They should be in a `Service`. Also, you don't have to store the file in memory, save it into a file to reduce the number of times the GC is running.

Comment: @OrphanC1 GC runs to clear heap(alomost certain), in that case what difference does it make while saving json to file or to sqlite database.

Comment: Because when saving into a file, you'd only be keeping a buffer of a set size in memory. Right now, you're keeping as much as you can.

Comment: Solved the issue by using transaction for inserting data into database. which reduces the total time by ten fold.